# Launchpad openid login problem

Tags: support, openid, login

My account on SO is rmyeid, I can not access the account anymore using the launchpad openid authentication server. I tried to figure what is the problem with launchpad support on the #launchpad irc channel. **deryck** said that problem is with SO.

The following is the conversation on #launchpad

<**aboSamoor**> do you know who I can ask regarding open id support ?

<**deryck**> aboSamoor, I haven't logged into stackoverflow before, but don't you have to associate your account on stack overflow with your LP account?

<**deryck**> aboSamoor, my guess is it wants to create a new stack overflow account because the site doesn't know which account your open id relates to.

<**aboSamoor**> deryck, I created an account in SO using launchpad openid, what I can remember that my id was id.launchpad.net/~rmyeid and after a while it changed to launchpad.net/~rmyeid and after that I can not access my account again !

<**deryck**> aboSamoor, what is your user name on Launchpad?

<**aboSamoor**> deryck, rmyeid

<**deryck**> aboSamoor, and when you went to SO did you try to provide -- https://launchpad.net/~rmyeid -- as your open id login?

<**aboSamoor**> deryck, I tried and it gives me that it is the first time so it will make a new user account !

<**deryck**> aboSamoor, Stack Overflow tells you it is your first time and wants you to create a new Stack Overflow account?  Is that correct?

<**aboSamoor**> deryck, yeah

<**deryck**> aboSamoor, yeah, this is what I was saying earlier.  Stack Overflow doesn't associate your open id with any account that they have.  I'm not sure why that is, but it's on Stack Overflow's end, not Launchpad's.

<**deryck**> aboSamoor, I think you need to contact someone with Stack Overflow about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sound's like Launchpad changed the address to the OpenID.

The easiest way to fix this is to email team@stackoverflow.com with the problem, and the problem accounts.

If you can, edit the duplicate, and write in the description that it is a dup of your other account. You may also want to edit the description of the original. This will help prove that the person who owns the duplicate account, is in fact the same person who owns the other account.

I have actually done this, and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: I can not access the original anymore !

Comment: Just do what you can, they will be able to figure it out.